# How can I use DI to create an instance of the page that I navigate to with my route?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms.shell

Here is the situation that I have:

I have set up a route like this:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("Cars/CarMgmtPage", typeof(CarMgmtPage));
```

When a button is clicked it calls the following:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Cars/CarMgmtPage", true);
```

However CarMgmtPage takes constructors in the argument like this;

```
public CarMgmtPage(IAddCar addCar1, 
                   IAddCar addCar2)
```

What I need to do is to use the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` that is used in my application to create this page something like this:

```
var abc = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CarMgmtPage>();
```

But I have no idea how to go about this as it seems the Xamarin Shell handles the creation of the page and I don't see how I can fit DI into that.

I hope someone has some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Why you want to create page yourself? maybe you need to use PushAsync then instead of GotoAsync?

Comment: CarMgmtPage has constructors that the DI needs to inject into. What I was wanting to do was to use the routing capabilities of the shell however I am open to other suggestions.  But if using PushAsync is that a problem in a shell application and is there something that will not happen if I do not use the routing?

Comment: I think it will affect your pages stack hierarchy, also take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: The link you supplies doesn't relate to the .Net Core Dependency Service that I am using which is: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: I have added an answer to this from the Xamarin team which says this is not correctly possible but planned.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that at this time this is not possible.  There are a couple of issues in the Xamarin Github talking about this:

```
[Enhancement] Dependency Injection support for creating ContentPage in Shell. #8359
```

Current status of this is:

Under consideration-High Interest in Enhancements on Jun 2, 2020

Also

```
[WiP] .NET MAUI Shell Improvements #10804
```

So the answer to this is that it we can hopefully expect this in the near future but right now it's still at the planning stage.